# How to add items to the TOC without automatically displaying the items?

Tags: arcmap, mapwindow

Is it possible to add items to the table of contents (ArcMap) without automatically displaying the items in the main window?

Comment: Are you asking about adding a layer into ArcMap TOC or MapWindow TOC?  You have a tag of MapWindow, but talk about ArcMap in your question.

Comment: Do you want to add them to ArcMap, but be invisible by default?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this question! I found a way to do a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if would like to to that programmatically, if not:

ArcMAP => Customize=> ArcMap Options => General Section => untick "Make newly added Layers visible by default"

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely certain of what it is you're trying to do...

It sounds like you may want to add a lyr without it displaying, useful in saving time. If working with the layoutview, you can use draft mode to add lyr's without displaying them.

layer properties > frame > draftmode (arcmap 10.0)